# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds Error Coding masters, please help me

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on collecting and pre-processing Excel data written in 2021.

My code is given below:

```
AE_cor = pd.DataFrame()
    global fnames
    for i in fnames: 
        # AE_team = pd.read_excel(f'{i}', header = 3)
        AE_team = pd.read_excel(f'{i}')
        team = AE_team.iloc[5,0]
        date = AE_team.iloc[0,5]
```

'fname' contains multiple Excel file paths received from the QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames.

Present output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\My\Desktop\python workspace\.vscode\business_expenses\Agency_expense.py", line 71, in create_table
    team = AE_team.iloc[5,0]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 889, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1450, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 723, in _has_valid_tuple
    self._validate_key(k, i)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1358, in _validate_key
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1444, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

The strange thing is that the Excel file written in 2020 works well. Why is there such an error? Is there anyone who can help you understand the error?

Comment: Just to make sure: you do have at least 6 rows in your dataset, right?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late comment, The index in the dataset ranges from o to 36

Comment: Try ```print(AE_team.head(10))``` before ```team = AE_team.iloc[5,0]```; maybe one of your DataFrames isn't being loaded the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much. When I looked up the Excel data, one file was empty. It works well when I remove this file.

Comment: glad it helped. I wrote it out as an answer with the solution as a general debugging tip for when you encounter the error in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` is telling you that one of the DataFrames doesn't have the number of rows or columns you expect it to have.

Running `print(AE_team.head(10))` before `team = AE_team.iloc[5,0]` will likely help you figure out which one (the one that triggers the error).